# Binding necessary at all times?

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm writing a program that a user will enter a computer name, the computer will be validated (DNS checks, pings, permissions checks through WMI, etc) and then the entered computer name will become a "validated" computer in a different textbox.  The user can then do various things to the validated computer like reboot, shutdown, WMI queries, etc.

Is WPF binding even worth it for something as simple as taking a user's input from one textbox and performing a ping and if the ping is successful, put the value into another textbox?  Can you bind a textbox value to a property then work with that value in the code behind?

Comment: `Is WPF binding even worth it for something as simple as taking a user's input from one textbox and performing a ping and if the ping is successful` - Yes. `Can you bind a textbox value to a property then work with that value in the code behind` - Yes. Have a look at MVVM if you haven't already and try to base your application on it for a better WPF experience overall.

Comment: So anything having to do with getting or setting a value to the UI should be bound?  Seems to be a lot of overhead for simple operations.

Answer (score 2):

Binding is always worth it. You sure can bind a TextBox Text to a public property and change the get method of that property to your will. Also, check Converters out if the returned type doesn't match the type needed in the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Network tasks have may have an unpredictable latency so separating from the UI code makes sense. You can consider different thread if delay affects user experience.